# Prove that the function series is uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis

We have $a_n = e+1-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ and we know that $a_n > 1$.
Define the function$$\begin{array}{rccc}f_n\colon&\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&{a_n}^x\cos x.\end{array}$$

I want to show that the function series is uniformly convergent. 
I assumed that $f(x) = \cos x$.
My attempt:
\begin{align*}|f_n(x)-f(x)|&= | (e+1-(1+1/n)^n)^x\cos(x)-\cos(x)| \\& \leq \left|(e+1-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n)^x\right|\end{align*}
We know that $1 \geq cos(x) \geq 0$, thats why I eliminated both cos(x).
Now I am not sure if I did it correct but I know that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ converges (for $n$ to $\infty$) to $e$. Thus it should be uniformly convergent but I don't know how to show this mathematiqually from this point. Appricate any help.

Comment: You proved it, since you have a bound for the difference $|f_n(x)−f(x)|$ that doesn't depend on $x$ and $\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$: exactly that is the meaning of "uniformly".

Comment: You have already demonstrated uniform convergence since your bound does not depend on $x$.

Comment: Ok, I used to finish the prove with .. $  \leq$ ϵ but I will look up the definition for uniform convergence again. Thanks

Comment: There is a problem, though: you estimate an expression containing $a_n\cos x$, but your definition of $f_n(x)$ contains $(a_n)^x\cos x$.

Comment: Indeed, then the full prove is not correct

Comment: Now I tried it again but I am stuck at the same position. I don't know how to eliminate the x from the power. (Post in the top is edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** note that for $\varepsilon > 0$:

$$ | (1+\varepsilon)^x |\leq (1+\varepsilon)^{\pi/2} < (1+\varepsilon)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $a^x$ is increasing with $x$. To bound that expression, you just need to pick a maximum value of $x$.